# The script for multiple asynchronous Html.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I prepared a page with products and their details. Details are to appear when you press the button. Using a foreach loop I generated tables with the products and a link to the details.
Unfortunately, only the top-form works asynchronously. Others open partialView. What should I do to make the script work for all forms?

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
      IdPromo
    </th>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.crosspromocje)
{ 
  <tr>
    <td>
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "promo", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-form"} ))
       { 
       @Html.Hidden("IdPromo ", item.IdPromo)
        <input type="submit" value="@item.IdPromo" />
       }
    </td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>    <div id="result"></div>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { 
            $("#my-form").on("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: this.action,
                        type: this.method,
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#result").html(data);
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

`

Comment: There is an Html-Helper called @Ajax.BeginForm which does the same but async.

Comment: Do you know about `@(using (Ajax.BeginForm(`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was necessary to change the id to a class.
From:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "xp", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-form}))
$("#my-form").on("submit", function (e)
```

To:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "xp", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "my-form" }))
$(".my-form").on("submit", function (e)
```